# Show Text Form Field error outside the styling of the field

Tags: flutter

I put some simple styles around my text field widget but when the validation kicks in, it disturbs the decoration. How do I show the error message after the field

[image]

Code:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  child: Material(
    elevation: 2,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
    child: new TextFormField(
      maxLines: 1,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: constFieldDecoration.copyWith(
        hintText: 'Title',
      ),
      validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Title can\'t be empty' : null,
      onSaved: (value) => _addTitle = value.trim(),
    ),
  ),
);

const constFieldDecoration = InputDecoration(
  hintText: 'Enter a value',
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1.0),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1.0),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
);
```

Comment: When I tested your code, there is a some problem. So I changed to ```decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Title',
      ),```. It looks fine.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the decoration I used. Updated the question now.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. For posterity, the Material wrap was the issue - removing it and styling the TextFormField itself directly worked.